# Customized Scrollable EditText in Scrollview Makes the Scrollview Jumps

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I want to have a EditText in a scrollview and this EditText needs to be scrollable. So I made a customized one as follow:

```
public class myEditText extends EditText {

    public myEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public myEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public myEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

This EditText has only one problem, that is when the text gets really long, the Scrollview containing it jumps for some reason. This makes me unable to edit text after a certain length. Is anyone know why that happens?

Comment: Do you want to scroll inside of edittext?

Comment: Yes I do. That's the requirement from the designer. The current issue is that if the content is not really long, then it works perfectly fine. The only problem is when the content gets really long, and when the cursor is set to the end of the text, the ScrollView jumps. Just like it starts to auto scrolls down.

Comment: Post your layout here, please.

Comment: It's just an EditText inside of a Scrollview

Comment: I finally solved it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it.

The issue was when there is a cursor in the EditText, the bringPointIntoView(int offset) method will make EditText scroll to the position where the cursor is at, so that the cursor will be in your sight and you can edit the text. Usually that's how it works, but when the EditText is in a ScrollView, instead of scroll the EditText, it makes the ScrollView scrolls as well. That's the reason I saw the ScrollView jumps.

The solution is simply override the bringPointIntoView method.

So if anyone wants to use a scrollable EditText in a ScrollView, I think this may help:

```
public class myEditText extends EditText {

    public myEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public myEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public myEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean bringPointIntoView(int offset) {
        return false;
    }
}
```